# Same processes, different CPU usage

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, troubleshooting

I have 2 Raspberry PI 3 Model B machines. They have exactly the same hardware and the same OS, the default one (Debian Jessie) provided by Raspberry.

I use those machines to run a Ruby On Rails application. Besides the application (the same in both machines), there are also several background tasks and jobs.

The problem is that when I monitor the CPU and RAM usage with `htop`, `top`, or any other tool, I get different CPU usage for the same processes in those machines.

[image]
[image]

You can notice this by comparing the pictures above. I marked `unicorn` process as an example. You can see an extreme diff between them **0%** vs. **78.8%**.

Nonetheless, the machines are not a clone of each-other. There are tools which might be installed in one of them and not in the other one.

I tried to bring the machines in the same conditions, killing/stopping those processes which were different for both machines and left only the same processes, but nothing changed.

Considering this circumstances:

1. Has anyone ever experienced this situation before?
2. How should I continue the debug now? What is that reason that might cause this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are underlining `unicorn master` in the top picture, but `unicorn worker` in the bottom.  You can see that `unicorn worker` is using about the same amount of resources in both pictures. You can also see that the top system is heavily loaded by some `watch_for_packages.rb` Ruby scripts.

Comment: You still have the four CPU-consuming processes running on the top system. Compare the two systems when those processes are finished, or kill them (if that's OK) and then compare. In general, it is hard to get two systems to behave the same way: a lot depends on things like differen cron jobs, network traffic, timing variations and who knows what else.